# Is it possible to transfer wifi settings from an android device to windows?

Tags: windows-8.1, android, wifi-configuration, data-transfer

I have the information from a few wifi networks saved on an android device, is there any way to move this data over to windows 8.1? I have exported the .txt file from android that contains the configuration (plain-text passwords and all), but I am not sure where to put it in windows, and what format it would need to be in.

edit: sample of the wifi configuration file (located at /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf) from an android device:

```
network={
    ssid="Network1"
    psk="xxx"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    priority=30
}

network={
    ssid="Network2"
    scan_ssid=1
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP IEEE8021X
    eap=PEAP
    identity="uname"
    password="pword"
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    priority=32
    proactive_key_caching=1
}
```

Ideally some way to copy over many of these networks would be preferred, however a manual one-by-one solution would also be acceptable.

update: it seems like the wifi properties in windows are saved as an xml file under:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces{InterfaceID}{something}.xml

Any info as to a schema or mapping for this xml file would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can export the wireless settings from a W8.1 PC to an xml file (something along the lines of `netsh wlan export profile key=clear` according to [Export & Import Wireless Network Info on Windows machines](http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/24989-export-import-wireless-network-info-on-windows-machines)) to see the required format, then you might be able to figure out a way to convert the JSON-like format from the Android device to an XML file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to import a wireless network as an xml file, but this has to pass through
the [netsh command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755301%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Here is for example the file defining a wireless connection using WPA2-PSK AES
and specifying the pass-phrase as unencrypted plain text:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>SSID-NAME</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <hex>SSID-NAME-in-hex</hex>
            <name>SSID-NAME</name>
        </SSID>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>false</protected>
                <keyMaterial>UNENCRYPTED-PASS-PHRASE</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

The description of all the above xml elements can be found in the Microsoft documentation at:
[WLAN_profile Schema Elements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms706965%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

This xml file can be imported into Windows via the command :

```
netsh wlan add profile filename="PATH_AND_FILENAME.xml"
```

Please note that while the pass-phrase can be unencrypted in the imported file,
Windows will encrypt it when it places the profile contents in the configuration file,
which as you already found is stored in :

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\{GUID}\{GUID}.xml
```

Here each wireless device is represented by a randomly assigned GUID interface name
of the form `{xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx}`.

Further reading :

[Importing and Exporting Windows Network Settings](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1597099)
[Exposing the WiFi Password Secrets](http://securityxploded.com/wifi-password-secrets.php)
[Two ways to push WLAN profiles to your Windows devices](http://www.commsolutions.com/blog/articles/two-ways-to-push-wlan-profiles-to-your-windows-devices/)